# Increasing literacy rate of non-accepted cultures in Victoria 2

Tags: victoria-2

I tried to find the information about it but I feel lost.

How do I educate non-accepted cultures to raise their literacy rate?

EDIT: Do they get educated by accepted culture bureaucrats?